# What stanford core nlp relation dependencies represent

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using coreNLP library in a project to generate Enhanced++ Dependencies. We can try using this link https://corenlp.run/. 
But I am not getting any proper list of what all these dependencies represent.
for example:

- nmod:under
- ref
- acl:recl

I am not getting any proper documentation of all these. There is something called Universal Dependencies but it has two versions and still I am not able to get the complete list

Comment: You can find information here: http://universaldependencies.org/

Comment: But it does not provide information about generic tags for example it gives information about nmod but i was not able to find nmod:under and similarly there are different cases. Although some of the generics are easy to interpret.